# How to initialize form group in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I have the following ngOnInit method:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.countries = this.sharedService.getCountries();
    this.shopService.getCurrentShopFromCache().then(shop => {
        this.shop = shop;
        this.myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
            name: [this.shop.name[this.shop.defaultLanguage.code], [Validators.required]],
            address: [this.shop.address.address],
            city: [this.shop.address.city],
            state: [this.shop.address.state],
            country: [this.shop.address.country, [Validators.required]],
            phone: [this.shop.phone],
            email: [this.shop.email],
            website: [this.shop.social.website],
            twitter: [this.shop.social.twitter],
            facebook: [this.shop.social.facebook],
            instagram: [this.shop.social.instagram],
            foursquare: [this.shop.social.foursquare]
        });
    }
    );
}
```

I'm getting

```
formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

Where am I wrong?

UPDATE:

```
 <form *ngIf="shop" class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right" [formGroup]="myFormGroup" novalidate>
                       ...
```

Comment: Please add template. Seems myFormGroup is undefined at first time

Comment: I added the form tag

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Sure. I couldn't find the way. Where should I instantiate the formGroup?

Comment: I tried again with a shop that has  address.address value and the problem was solved. So how to initialize the form with some null fields?

Comment: Try to create simple form. Your code looks good

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<strike>You have to instantiate formgroup immediately on component creation, i.e. in the constructor, otherwise angular just cannot find what to bind template properties to.</strike>

**UPDATE**

Rephrasing: you have to instantiate form group before template gets rendered by angular. It's stricter than angular 1.x and throws an error if it cannot evaluate expression in template binding at the time of html form rendering.

Since you're using `*ngIf="shop"` in the template I'd say it means that `shop` turns not null **before** then() gets executed - maybe initially, maybe by some other function - it's not in the code you provided, so I can't point it out.

What you're trying to do is to initialize form with some data fetched by some service. That's totally fine - but it's still no reason to postpone ***creation*** of controls. Just create them in the constructor and set values later in the ngOnInit using [FormGroup's](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) [setValue()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setValue), [patchValue()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchValue) or [reset()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset) - depending on what exactly you need. Below is just the idea, you'll need to adjust it to your form structure.

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    formGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.formGroup = fb.group({
            title: fb.control('initial value', Validators.required)
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.formGroup.reset({title: 'new value'});
    }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <input type="text" formControlName="title">
</form>
```

Comment: `You have to instantiate formgroup immediately on component creation` Why? I think his code should work https://plnkr.co/edit/UwBTLPDAblb5ja33ZHwr?p=preview `angular just cannot find what to bind template properties ` Angular will bind properties as soon as ngIf becames true

Comment: @yurzui, because I missed that ngIf. :( You're right, I'll update my answer to reflect that. Still, at any point in time form group must exist before template gets rendered by angular - in this case as soon as "shop" turns to be "truthy". So yes, there should be something else wrong with OP's code - probably because "shop" is not null initially or gets filled up by something else before that async call finishes and creates form group... and angular does try to render this form without form group.

Comment: You can use `patchValue` or any other function in place of `reset` mentioned here - https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#methods